# Specific time of the availability of the agents

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Is it possible to set a time for the availability of the agents in studio flow?

For example:
The business hours are 8am - 6pm. If the customer call at 6:30pm then an automated message will tell the customer regarding the business hours.

Is there a such a function in studio flow to determine the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to code this part up yourself, below are a few blog posts of interest. Basically, you will Twilio Functions and the Studio Run Function widget to achieve this.

[Advanced Schedules for Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/advanced-schedules-studio)

[Using Twilio Functions to Add Custom JavaScript Code in Studio Flows](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/custom-javascript-twilio-functions-code-studio-flows.html)